# How do I reverse a transaction?

Tags: transactions, address

Ok here is the thing I lost coins on this computer trying to send them to my laptop this is what it said

```
Status: 0/unconfirmed
Date: 2/6/2013 14:53
To: 1PrM4QW3UtkGhi1uXFjvtDhn3h3x3pMipn
Debit: -3.98
Net amount: -3.98
```

How do I reverse it or stop it its been over a month and I cant seem to find how to do it.

Comment: Here's what I think you're really asking: "I sent bitcoins to an address, but those bitcoins never showed up on the other end. How do I fix this?" Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't lose them, they were successfully sent. You can see the confirmed transaction [here](http://blockexplorer.com/tx/23019a829c1f45f59b8ee2aaf62de3e02b8adbae1be83fc5ca1de07b4214d5f9), included in block 219,976.

In fact, the recipient [spent them](http://blockexplorer.com/tx/8ebc8838ca450deacee790dfbe3e3346b934f1aa930735a04e13024e03d96f87#i26575581) (sending them to 1ESTZpJUkqSQDkjyQHYAFecasEykhFWmMj) about 9 hours later.